# Using Python to overwrite resource section in C program

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedded-resource, portable-executable

I have a C program that has a resource section.

```
IDS_STRING 87 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

In the hex editor it looks like this

[image]

I use code such as this in Python to search and replace the A's:

```
str = b'\x00A'*40
str1 = b"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"

if str in file:
    print("A in file")
    f.write(file.replace(str, str1))
```

This makes the new file look like this:

[image]

So I am wondering why the A's are stored like '41 00' and then when I overwrite them they are just '42'.

Is this a WCHAR thing?

I did a test where I loaded the string and printed it out.

```
This is some text.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

But then when I used my Python and overwrote the A's with the B's it does this..

```
This is some text.???????????????????????????????????????B
```

So with my limited knowledge of C, If I want to put things into the resource section I should place them in as WCHAR?

UPDATE:
My main issue with this is I have a hex string similar to below:

```
'685308358035803507835083408303508350835083508350835083083508'
```

I want to put that into the resource section. But if I do that similar to the way I am replacing, so by doing

```
f.write(file.replace(str, '685308358035803507835083408303508350835083508350835083083508'))
```

Then it puts it into the resource section as:

[image]

If it goes in like this, it causes things to break because it is grabbing 2 bytes at a time it seems like.

The reason I am asking this is because when I replace the A's with my hex and run the program. It does not work. But if I place the hex directly into the resource section in Visual Studio and run it, it does work. When I replace with Python it is '34322424...' but when the same string is placed in the resource section is it '3400220042004....'

2nd UPDATE:
It seems that the resource section string table does store in a 2 bytes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#the-rsrc-section

```
Resource Directory Strings 
Two-byte-aligned Unicode strings, which serve as string data that is pointed to by directory entries.
```

Comment: replace them by `bs = b'\x00B'*40` ? Your B's take only halve the space of the A's ...

Comment: I updated my first post. I can do what you suggested, but that only works for something small like that. I am generating a hex string and I am wanting to put that into the resource section. Then when the program runs, it will decrypt the string and use what it gets out of it. So I am wondering, should I take my hex string and add '00' after each byte? So that it fits into the resource section just like the A's '41 00'?

Comment: What is a "resource section" in a C program, and why does the `C` language bear any significance in this question? This look plain like editing a binary file. The best solution: don't ever edit binary files, edit C sources. And yes, if you use `wchar_t` it is (as all is) implementation defined type and may be 2 (or more) bytes long and may use implementation defined manner to store characters in 2 bytes with zeros between, why not. As you use visual studio, one can assume it's windows, so yes - wchar_t is (probably) 2 bytes long. Stil unclear what are you trying to do and why is C relevant

Comment: Why would you make a comment if you don't even know what I am talking about?

Comment: @Halloween The fact that the program you’re editing the binary of is written in C is indeed irrelevant. You’re editing Windows resource records, and their structure is independent of the programming language used to implement the binary. So Kamil is correct. Additionally, your simple editing is usable, but you have to verify your assumptions and check that there are no other long strings of A’s in the binary: you expect only one string, if there’s more then you don’t know which one to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like utf-16 encoding. So you can use regular python unicode strings, and make sure you open and write to the file in text mode, and with utf16 encoding.

If you use binary mode, each ascii character you write will be represented in a single byte. If you use text mode, each character you write will be represented by two bytes. If the text you write is only using low unicode code points, there will be a bunch of null bytes. If you write some Chinese text, you need both bytes.

The hex dump you posted don't show a BOM at the start, so you might have to use `utf-16le` instead of `utf-16`.

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16le') as fp:
    text = fp.read()

with open('foo.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-16le') as fp:
    fp.write(text.replace('AAAAAA', 'BBBBBB'))
```